# Could not generate DH keypair error with sales force API calls

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

We used Java 7 and Tomcat 8 before the Java 8 migration and we couldn't face any issues.

But after migrating to Java 8, we are getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:82)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:783)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        ... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:77)
        ... 139 common frames omitted
```

This error happens when we call the salesforce API calls.

**Note:** With the same configuration(Java 8 and Tomcat 8) we don't get this error in our DEV environment.

Can anyone please advise, how can I resolved this issue?

I found same type of questions in stack overflow but still no luck.

Comment: what's the exact java version?

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42252911/3888766

Comment: We use jdk 8u181 and I upgraded to 8u201, but no luck